# Express Session / Cookie maxAge property refreshes on request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, session, cookies

Code in app.js

```
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser")
var session = require("express-session")


app.use(cookieParser())

app.set('trust proxy', 1)
app.use(session(
  {
    "name": '***',
    "secret": '***',
    "cookie": {
      "maxAge": null,
      "expires": null,
      "httpOnly": true,
      "secure": true
    },
    "rolling": false,
    "saveUninitialized": false,
    "resave": false,

}))
```

When logging in this end point gets hit

```
req.session.username = email    // defaults to putting something in cookie
    req.session.cookie.maxAge = 1000 * 5
    req.session.touch()
```

Test: finding the time left for cookie/session

```
router.get('/refresh-session', function(req, res){
    if (req.session){
        console.log(req.session.username)
        console.log(req.session.cookie.maxAge)
    }

})
```

My goal is to display a popup to the user in react notifying them that their session is about to expire. I will be refreshing the maxAge every time they navigate to a new page... However, before that I need to find out what the actual current maxAge is. Doing so seems to refresh the maxAge of the cookie. But this maxAge refresh isn't actually effecting the expiration time.

For example:
If maxAge is set to 5 seconds (testing purposes) then calling the method to check the maxAge will consistently be between 4800-5000 millis. However, after the 5 seconds - no matter how many times I refresh - the cookie does expire at 5 seconds (which is intended).

**The thing is why id maxAge reseting?**

I've looked around and found some unhelpful git pages. Here:
https://github.com/expressjs/session/issues/189#issuecomment-182631933 - doesn't work
https://github.com/expressjs/session/issues/2 - **very unhelpful**

Anyone run into this issue or can suggest alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `req.session.cookie.maxAge` tells how much time is left in the session. It is reset at end of request to original value. This is documented in the [README.md](https://github.com/expressjs/session#cookiemaxage-1).

Your frontend can not ask the backend for how much of session is still left, because the session is *touched* at the request. You can set the `cookie.maxAge` already at the session parameters, no need to postpone until login. Your frontend should keep own timer and reset it at every request to backend.